# How does Vue overwrite jQuery event listeners

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I have read that jQuery and Vue tend not to work very well together (see eg. https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/). As I have a large jQuery app that I am progressively incorporating Vue into, I'd like to understand what's going on under the hood so I can avoid conflicts.

Here's a simplified test page:

```js
$('#a').click(function() {
  alert('a');
});

$(function() {
  $('#b').click(function() {
    alert('b');
  });
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '.container',
  mounted: function() {
    $('#c').click(function() {
      alert('c');
    });
  }
});

$('#d').click(function() {
  alert('d');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button id="a">a - jQuery immediate</button>
  <button id="b">b - jQuery DOM ready</button>
  <button id="c">c - jQuery inside Vue mounted</button>
  <button id="d">d - jQuery after Vue</button>
</div>
```

As you can see, the first (a) event listener gets wiped out by Vue whereas the other three (b - d) continue to work.

My question boils down to, *at a technical level, what is Vue doing to (a) which is different from (b) or (d)?*

**CodePen here:** https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/PxzQNq

Comment: A is bound when the script runs. If anything destroys and recreates that element (such as possibly Vue initializing), the binding will be lost.  B is bound after the document has been fully parsed into the DOM.  Which is past the point that all this script runs.  Vue runs and initializes, which may destroy the exising A element and create it anew, destroying the original binding.  C is bound once Vue is mounted.  D is bound once Vue is done doing what it is going to do.  So if Vue redraws the page before it gets to that point, D will be bound to the (new) D element.

Comment: But beyond that, the point here is, **do not use jQuery to bind when you code with Vue**.  Use the vue click directives to do your bindings on the elements, and do not use jQuery to do that.  Ref. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Listening-to-Events

Comment: I think you should avoid using jquery with VueJS, Angular and React.

Comment: Your buttons are actually `type="submit"` because you omited the type. Are you sure that is helpful?

Comment: @connexo it makes no difference for this demo.

Comment: Please add your code as a snippet next time unless SO snippet functionality is not sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `.container` (the `el`) gets replaced by Vue right after the `beforeMount` event fires, and right before the `mounted` event fires. You can see a diagram here:

[image]

([reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram))

To illustrate:

```js
const a = document.querySelector('#a')
const app = new Vue({
  el: '.container',
  beforeMount: () => {
    console.log(a === document.querySelector('#a'));
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log(a === document.querySelector('#a'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Vue vs jQuery</h1>
  <button id="a">button</button>
</div>
```

As you can see, the original `a` gets lost right after `beforeMount`, right before `mounted`. The effect is the same as if the innerHTML of the container was altered, eg

```
document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML += ' ';
```

Comment: Thanks, @CertainPerformance. Much as you've suggested, I've added some console.logs to the CodePen and I see that the (b) event listener is the last to be added.

Comment: I'd have thought that Vue only affects the HTML elements which contain directives, but apparently not.